# Django html script in TextField of a model

Tags: html, django

I created a mail model that has the following properties

```
class Mail(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sender')
    to = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='receiver')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    sent_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('mail-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

I am trying to add a link that redirects to the detail of the request in the content section of the mail.
This is what I tried

```
m = Mail(
    sender=self.request.user,
    to=self.get_object().student,
    title='Request Comfirmed',
    content=f'Your request has been confirmed by {self.request.user.username}.' + '\n<small class="text-muted"><a class="ml-2" href="{% url \'request-defail\' ' + str(self.get_object().id) + ' %}">Click here to view details of the request</a></small>'
)
```

This is what happened
[image]

And this is how the mail is displayed

```
<article class="media content-section">
    <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ object.sender.profile.image.url }}" alt="">
    <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
            <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-profile' object.sender.username %}">{{ object.sender.username }}</a>
            <small class="text-muted">{{ object.sent_time }}</small>
        </div>
        <h2 class="article-titile">{{ object.title }}</h2>
        <p class="article-content">{{ object.content }}</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make what you want, you need to add the [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#:%7E:text=%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%20Django%22.-,safe,-%C2%B6) filter at te end.

```
<p class="article-content">{{ object.content|safe }}</p>
```

Comment: The url in href="{% url 'request-defail' self.get_object().id %}" won't work, is there a way to do it

Comment: Yes you can use the `reverse` function. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/urlresolvers/